# Pandas. After Pivot, Change Column Level

Tags: python, pandas

I have use the following pivot function to create a table like this.

```
pf.pivot(index='model',columns=['Dataset'],values=['ap_score','roc_score'])
```

[image]

But I am trying to do the format like the following picture. I am trying to switch the column level. But `Index.get_level_values` return that those column are on the same level.
[image]

Can somebody help me please! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and then [`df.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on the new level 0 column index, as follows:

```
df = df.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

### Demo

```
data = {('ap_score', 'cora'): [1, 2],
 ('ap_score', 'flickr'): [11, 22],
 ('roc_score', 'cora'): [101, 102],
 ('roc_score', 'flickr'): [111, 122]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


  ap_score        roc_score       
      cora flickr      cora flickr
0        1     11       101    111
1        2     22       102    122

df = df.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)


print(df)

      cora             flickr          
  ap_score roc_score ap_score roc_score
0        1       101       11       111
1        2       102       22       122
```